# windows azure media service for storing, Retrieving, Version etc..

Tags: azure-storage, azure-media-services

Can we perform below task on Windows Azure Media Service that is 
storing, Retrieving,maintaining Version of Video, Permission handling, Searching for the video 
for each tenant on the SaaS environment

Answer (score 0):

Currently Azure Media services providing infrastructure to ingest, encode and deliver media assets. Complex metadata, versioning, access control and additional content management functionality can be extended by third party providers or in your application. 
Short answer that for now Windows Azure Media Service is not positioned as CMS system with listed in your question functionality.

You can use Asset.AlternativeId to store any keys from external system which can be built on top of Windows Azure Media Service.